# Adding an exception to ProxyCommand in ssh config file

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

How to add a ProxyCommand to all the ssh hosts except for abc.com

I tried the following lines in `~/.ssh/config` file but it does not work.

```
    Host *
      ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x proxy.com:8080 %h %p

    Host abc.com
      ProxyCommand NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu's man page for ~/.ssh/config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

> **Host**
>
> ......
>
> A pattern entry may be negated by prefixing it with an
>                exclamation mark ('!').  If a negated entry is matched, then the
>                Host entry is ignored, regardless of whether any other patterns
>                on the line match.  Negated matches are therefore useful to
>                provide exceptions for wildcard matches.

Thus your problem can be solved as follows:

> Host !abc.com
>
> ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x proxy.com:8080 %h %p